# using *args and **kwargs as a substitute for function's arguments

Tags: python, function, args

I hava a question about *args and **kwargs. I know that they are used when you do not know how many arguments will be passed to function. But can it be a substitute for some arguments that are actually required when I do not know what those are?

If there is a function:

```
def functionName(a, b):
    ...some code...
    doSomethingUsing(a)
    doSomethingUsing(b)
```

If I do not what arguments does the function take can I simply use functionName(*args, **kwargs) - or functionName(*args)? I noticed that some people tend to use it that way - but I am not sure if this is how * and ** work in python?

Comment: The calls `functionName(*args)` are *unpacking* whatever `args` is into `functionName`.

Comment: You can look at Peter Hoffmann's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/6683117

Comment: This question is not clear and probably a duplicate. It sounds like you just want to throw arbitrary arguments at a function and it should magically know what it needs. You always have to know what arguments a function takes, how else can you be sure that you're using it correctly? Please clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, I suspected I am going to get downvoted for that - but it was worth it - thanks for the answers and links it is much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `function(*args)` is equivalent to `function(arg[0], arg[1],...,arg[N])`.

If you don't know what arguments the function is expecting, just call it and look at the exception:

```
>>> def f(a,b,c):
...     pass
...
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', and 'c'
```

Or you could use the interactive `help`.

```
>>> help(f)
Help on function f in module __main__:

f(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use the *args and **kwargs at the same time but the orders matters you can have the idea [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/). if you want to use all two of these in functions then the order is

```
some_func(*args,**kwargs)
```